# GoDaddy parker site when viewing site on mobile phone

Tags: hosting, godaddy

I have this URL hosted on GoDaddy: http://timkl.com

When I view it in Chrome on my Desktop it works fine.

However when I view it on a mobile phone, I get a GoDaddy parker site.

I'm flummoxed, what could be wrong, and how do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: If you just setup your DNS settings, they likely haven't propagated fully (can take up to 24-48 hrs, although, it is usually faster). Your phone probably uses different DNS servers than your desktop.

Comment: Haven't changed my DNS settings in the last year.

Comment: The Whois record for the above domain says it was updated yesterday (Last Updated on: 01-Jan-12). The DNS lookup returns a GoDaddy IP for the A record (68.178.232.100) and I see the GoDaddy parking page. Verify you DNS settings, even if you haven't changed them, and check the DNS response from both sources (e.g. with `dig timkl.com` or `nslookup timkl.com`).

Answer (score 1):

DNS records can take up to three days to propagate with different providers refreshing at different times. Wait a couple of days and this problem should go away.